# Keeping Linux configuration files in SVN (Subversion)

Tags: linux, security, svn

How good is the idea of ​​preserving the **Linux** configuration files in version control system (**SVN**, for example)? For example, to see all changes in the firewall, change history. In particular, it is possible to keep these groups of files -

- Access files
- Booting and login / logout
- File system
- System administration
- Networking
- System commands
- Daemons

...

Ie For example, I am making changes to the firewall and do commit the file to the repository. Then, if something goes not so, I can extract the file and compare it to that is. This can help detect some unauthorized access.

Comment: For configuration files it's okay. Backups (of blobs) may not be what you want to do with a VCS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is old hat, so to speak.

Chek [this](http://joeyh.name/code/etckeeper/) out.

Comment: etckeeper is also based on the git vcs.

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer yep, but it should work with Mercurial and a few others as well.